# Getting export link in Google Drive API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the Google Drive Ruby Client and am trying to export some sheets documents into a CSV format. I can get my file fine, but when trying to access the `exportLinks` it doesn't seem to exist on my file, even though it does return it in the API Explorer on Google's site. Here is how I am trying to get the `exportLink` currently:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => APPLICATION_NAME)
client.authorization = authorize
drive_api = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')

result = client.execute!(
               :api_method => drive_api.files.get,
               :parameters => {:fileId => "1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q"})
file = result.data
puts("Fetched #{file["title"]}")
puts("Getting downloadURL")
exportLinks = file['exportLinks']['text/csv']
```

I keep getting an error saying "undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).' So for some reason I am not getting anything returned from `exportLinks`. Anyone know why this is? Have the methods changed, but not yet updated on the API Explorer? Am I making some other stupid mistake? Am I missing a comma somewhere? Any help is extremely appreciated!

Let me know if you need any more code.

Edit -- Stack trace:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/billluhmann/Developer/OpinionLab-Automation/autoimport.rb
Doing some Google Drive stuff
Fetched Test Spreadsheet
Getting downloadURL
/Users/billluhmann/Developer/OpinionLab-Automation/autoimport.rb:163:in     `main': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/billluhmann/Developer/OpinionLab-Automation/autoimport.rb:237:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Edit 2: I logged out the response I'm getting... And it is indeed not including the exportLinks.

Here is the (relevant part of the) response my application sees:

```
"parents": [
{
 "kind": "drive#parentReference",
 "id": "0AJj4OUAR-EvNUk9PVA",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q/parents/0AJj4OUAR-EvNUk9PVA",
 "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AJj4OUAR-EvNUk9PVA",
 "isRoot": true
}
],
"userPermission": {
"kind": "drive#permission",
"etag": "\"OAy0CkbWKifm-WnYBAdgx1dwNXA/IGgJsRJ105V1BXysjoqMdW7TLx8\"",
"id": "me",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q/permissions/me",
"role": "owner",
"type": "user"
},
```

And the response API Explorer shows me I should get:

```
"parents": [
{

"kind": "drive#parentReference",
"id": "0AJj4OUAR-EvNUk9PVA",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q/parents/0AJj4OUAR-EvNUk9PVA",
"parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AJj4OUAR-EvNUk9PVA",
"isRoot": true
}
],
"exportLinks": {
"text/csv": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q&exportFormat=csv",
"application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q&exportFormat=pdf",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q&exportFormat=xlsx"
},
"userPermission": {
"kind": "drive#permission",
"etag": "\"OAy0CkbWKifm-WnYBAdgx1dwNXA/IGgJsRJ105V1BXysjoqMdW7TLx8\"",
"id": "me",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q/permissions/me",
"role": "owner",
"type": "user"
},
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this help, but in the sharing setting UI of the shared google sheet that I am trying to use the google drive api for, if I check `Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers` checkbox, then the json response from google will NOT include the exportLinks entry